# Problem with SVN access control

Tags: svn, apache-2.2

I have the following access control file

```
[groups]
admin = robu, jjtl, dat
user  = ulo
[/]
@admin = rw
@user  = rw

[/wlp]
@admin = rw

[/wesys]
@admin = rw
@user  = rw
```

But the `user` group still can browse the `wlp`, how can I remove the access? It is working if a take out from the root([/]) but I don't want to do that because we are using trac for repository browsing.

Comment: Which SVN layout you are using: single repository for multiple projects or each project have its own repository?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
[/wlp]
@admin = rw
@user =
```

With subversion permissions, a user will inherit the permissions form the parent folder unless there's an explicit match that alters those permissions further down the directory tree. So in your case, `ulo` inherits read access to `/wlp` from the the root folder, since he's a member of `user` and `[/]` is the closest match to the path where permissions for that group are defined.

By explicitly defining `@user =` under `[/wlp]` you're giving svn a closer match to the requested path which specifically states 'no access'.

Answer (score 1):

how if ?

```
 [groups]
 admin = robu, jjtl, dat
 user  = ulo

 [/]
 @admin = rw
 *=r
```